# Django filter form not rendering

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-filter, django-template-filters

I'm using a FilterSet to perform a filtering over a set of product. First of all, here is my code :

models.py

```
class Plat(models.Model):
    titre = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.TextField(null = True)
    allergenes = models.TextField(null = True)
    prix = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Prix par portion")
    chef = models.ForeignKey('inscription.Chef', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    date_prep = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name="Date de préparation")
    nb_portions = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Nombre de portions disponibles")
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = "photos_plat/")
```

filters.py

```
class PlatFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Plat
        fields = {
            'titre': ['icontains'],
            'prix': ['lte', 'gte'],
            'nb_portions': ['gte'],
            'date_prep': ['exact'],
        }
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    plats = Plat.objects.all()
    filter = PlatFilter(request.GET, queryset=plats)
    return render(request, 'actualites/home.html', locals())
```

home.html

```
<form method="get">
  {{ filter.form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Everything is working perfectly but I want to make the form prettier and being able to customize the label names and so on so I use this code :

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<form method="get">
  <div class="well">
    <h4 style="margin-top: 0">Filtrer par</h4>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
          {{ filter.form.titre.label_tag }}
          {% render_field filter.form.titre class="form-control" %}
        </div>
      </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
         </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And here nothing is displayed except the "Filtrer par" and the submit button. I've correctly installed widget_tweaks. Why isn't it working ? I've made a few researchs and I was not able to find an answer.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Up please, I still haven't found an answer

Comment: Up ----------------------

Comment: Hi, I was running into the same issue with a different approach in a form, try getting rid of the <div class = "well" and see if it renders.